# Laravel 5.2 application deployment on production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bitbucket, web-deployment

I developed application in laravel 5.2. I was using the Virtual host on local and pointing publice/index.php easily.

But on production why we need to using the put index.php & all stuff out of public folder. Is this best practice to deploy on production?

I copied whole in project folder and public folder stuff copied on the root(public_html) of server.

I changed the index.php accordingly and its working fine.

```
require __DIR__.'/project/bootstrap/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/project/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Issue is When i use auto deployment tool, It pushes whole code in project folder. Every time I move assets by ssh from project/public/assets to root/assets manually.

**Main Issue**
I am also facing issue, saving profile picture in assets folder. But it save picture in project/public/asset instead it should in root/assets. I am really confused on this issue too.

**Advise me**
Please recommend me the best practice, where should i keep public folder stuff and how to manage auto deployment.

Can we keep index.php inside public and point directly index.php here. In this way auto deployment work fine.

**Issue in after deployment commands**
I am using DeployHQ.com to deploy my code. It execute ssh commands, but unfortunatly my command doesn't work because artisan file is inside of root/abc/project folder. I dont know where this shell execute commands. or How to point project folder directly to execute these commands.

**Bitbucket webhook return 422 error code**
I am using bitbucket webhook on approve event. I have given it deployment url and auto deployment is switched on. Hook triggerred as well, but it didn't deploy any thing, It shows error code 422 and error "Could not decode the deployement".

Comment: You are having too many problems please narrow it down to specific. `index.php` in public should be there and not get changed its only purpose is to load laravel and nothing more. Access to public folder should be allowed.. you might have wrong permissions on some other directories . You can also work with storage class to place files in storage directory and serve them only via routes that you use so you can restrict/control access. You should really read the guide it's explains in detail everything for deployment of laravel app, also use documentation of the service you use.

Comment: what kind of hosting your production server has?

Comment: Having a hosting on dedicated server.

Comment: @Mr.phoenix, Please explain, on production in cpanel how would i point to public/index.php. it doesn't work by default as you know. This is main issue.

Comment: Depends on web server, if you use apache try setting up an virtualhost and point to the public  directory, these are basics..if you lack the knowledge try reading the guides or get someone to do it for you.

Comment: I am already having Vhost on local in windows. But i wonder, How we do same in cPanel. no idea. or Is there better/stable solution for this? Thanks for your response @phoenix.

Answer (score 0):

The index.php file should be in the public folder. Everything else should not. Your web server should be configured to point to this directory.

The index.php file bootstraps the Laravel framework. The framework files should sit in a directory outside of the publicly accessible folder. This is usually in the directory above the public/ folder.

You shouldn't work around your deployment tool. It should be configured to maintain this directory structure. Once there is no confusion as to where files should be pushed, you can begin to solve your other path related deployment problems. To avoid future pain, I'd recommend setting up your dev environment as close to production as possible.

Comment: if my structure is public_html/abcd,So abcd is publically accessible folder. Where i should create folder which would not be publically accessbile?

Comment: By convention public_html/ should be your publicly accessible folder containing index.php. By default Laravel names this folder "public" -- but in your case it is called "public_html" and you need to configure your server to point to this as your document root. The Laravel framework files should sit one directory above this public folder.